# Upgrade ubuntu to a specific release

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I'm currently on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. As of writing this, 18.04 LTS is available. However, I do not wish to upgrade to it.
Instead, I would like to upgrade to 17.04 LTS.

I've done:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Many tutorials suggest

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

as the next step. But I believe that would upgrade to the latest distro and not the target 17.04.
How do I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, I don’t think Ubuntu officially supports upgrades to releases other than either the latest release or the latest LTS. It *might* be possible to upgrade to a specific release by changing the appropriate code name in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and running `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`, but that won’t take into account any upgrade step performed by the `do-release-upgrade` tool (if any).

However in your specific case, 17.04 isn’t an LTS, and is [already out of support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes). 16.04 is still supported; if you don’t want to upgrade to 18.04 you should stick with 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

So the obvious other answer is to [create a bootable usb](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) of the version that you want to upgrade to, and back up your current home directory, restoring it after you've completed the install. It's not elegant, but it works.

Comment: While this appears to address the question, I think it misses a point that [Stephen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463131/117549) makes, that their target OS, 17.04, is out of support.  Following the bootable USB link to [Requirements](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#2-requirements) to [Releases](https://releases.ubuntu.com/) shows that 17.04 isn't available as an ISO.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I see your point, and while that is correct regarding the specific version, which is no longer available, the answer is robust. If my answer had been more timely, ie. closer in time to the asking, 17.04 would have been an available ISO release. In perpetuity, would it make more sense to follow the advice of modifying the sources list?

Comment: Different questions have different scopes & requirements, so my recommendation is to try to find questions that you can successfully address.